# Setting Woocommerce Product Tags and Categories via Custom Frontend Form

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, woocommerce, categories

I am building a form for users to create a product via the frontend of my site using `wp_insert_post` and `update_post_meta`.

The problem arises when trying to set the product categories and tags. It seems Woocommerce doesn't use standard Wordpress taxonomies in this regard. Anyone have any experience with this? It seems Woocommerce uses `product_tags` in some places. Is there a function to create them similar to Wordpress?

Below is a snippet of what I am doing. Thanks!

```
$post = array(
 'ID' => '',
 'post_content' => $_POST['post_content'],
 'post_title' => $_POST['post_title'],
 'post_status' => 'draft',
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'post_author' => $user_id,
);

$newListing = wp_insert_post($post, $wp_error);

//SET META
update_post_meta($newListing, '_stock_status', 'instock', true);
update_post_meta($newListing, '_visibility', 'visible', true);
update_post_meta($newListing, '_price', $_POST['_regular_price'], true);

//SET CATEGORIES - **NOT WORKING**
wp_set_post_categories($newListing, $categories);

//SET THE TAGS **NOT WORKING**
wp_set_post_tags($newListing, $tags, true);
```

Answer (score 19):

Found out the built-in Wordpress function `wp_set_object_terms` will handle this quite easily.

Below are some examples:

```
//SET THE PRODUCT CATEGORIES
wp_set_object_terms($productID, array('Cat Name 1', 'Cat Name 2'), 'product_cat');

//SET THE PRODUCT TAGS
wp_set_object_terms($productID, array('tag1','tag2','tag3'), 'product_tag');
```

Comment: is there a way to show the tag box that appears in the post edit screen to bring it to our custom plugin, that would be really cool.

Answer (score 1):

use **wp_set_object_terms()** function and pass **array of term_id**

```
wp_set_object_terms($product_id, array(1,8,10), 'product_cat');
wp_set_object_terms($product_id, array(1,8,10), 'product_tag');
```