# Add tag to WooCommerce products based on discount percentage

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I combined the code from here [Setting Woocommerce Product Tags and Categories via Custom Frontend Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144139/setting-woocommerce-product-tags-and-categories-via-custom-frontend-form) with the code from here [Display the discount percentage on the sale badge in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558950/display-the-discount-percentage-on-the-sale-badge-in-woocommerce-3) :) and it looks like its working but I am not confident, what do you think?

for testing purposes I just added an if

```
if ($percentage > 15) {
    wp_set_object_terms($product->get_id(), array('tag5'), 'product_tag');  
  }
```

and I can see the tags on the back end/front end.

Thank you

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'add_percentage_to_sale_badge', 20, 3 );
function add_percentage_to_sale_badge( $html, $post, $product ) {

  if( $product->is_type('variable')){
      $percentages = array();

      // Get all variation prices
      $prices = $product->get_variation_prices();

      // Loop through variation prices
      foreach( $prices['price'] as $key => $price ){
          // Only on sale variations
          if( $prices['regular_price'][$key] !== $price ){
              // Calculate and set in the array the percentage for each variation on sale
              $percentages[] = round( 100 - ( floatval($prices['sale_price'][$key]) / floatval($prices['regular_price'][$key]) * 100 ) );
          }
      }
      // We keep the highest value
      $percentage = max($percentages) . '%';

  } elseif( $product->is_type('grouped') ){
      $percentages = array();

      // Get all variation prices
      $children_ids = $product->get_children();

      // Loop through variation prices
      foreach( $children_ids as $child_id ){
          $child_product = wc_get_product($child_id);

          $regular_price = (float) $child_product->get_regular_price();
          $sale_price    = (float) $child_product->get_sale_price();

          if ( $sale_price != 0 || ! empty($sale_price) ) {
              // Calculate and set in the array the percentage for each child on sale
              $percentages[] = round(100 - ($sale_price / $regular_price * 100));
          }
      }
      // We keep the highest value
      $percentage = max($percentages) . '%';

  } else {
      $regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price();
      $sale_price    = (float) $product->get_sale_price();

      if ( $sale_price != 0 || ! empty($sale_price) ) {
          $percentage    = round(100 - ($sale_price / $regular_price * 100)) . '%';

      } else {
          return $html;
      }
  }
  if ($percentage > 15) {
    wp_set_object_terms($product->get_id(), array('tag5'), 'product_tag');  
  }
  

  return '<span class="onsale">' . esc_html__( 'SALE', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ' . $percentage . '</span>'. $product->get_id();
}
```